# Twitter api for iPhone OS4

Tags: iphone, oauth, twitter, ios4, mgtwitterengine

It looks like the twitter api refused to work for iPhone OS4 :(
(Twitter+OAuth http://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone). 
When I building the project to which I just add the Twitter+OAuth I see the following:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/3ce52c447b.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/3ce52c447b.png)

It's really really important for me! Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks in advance!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there is a binary mismatch between the various object files.

Don't forget that iPhone 4.0 is a new major version, thus it may break ABI (Application Binary Interface). This means that you cannot take a binary object from iPhone 3.0 and link it with a iPhone 4.0 binary object without problems (Note that it may works, but unlikely).

I suggest you to re-build everything from the sources.

Comment: You're absolutely right as for the ABI. it's really sooo many problems with OS4!! so I need just rebuild the OAuthConsumer library (the only library in the Twitter+OAuth project) for Mac OS 10.6, right? (sources of library - http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/obj-c). Thanks for help!

Comment: Yes that's right. You need to rebuild from sources all the libraries involved in Twitter+OAuth project.

Comment: Yeeeh! It's working. I rebuilt the OAuthConsumer library from the Twitter+OAuth project (http://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone) and errors disappears. Now I know that all the lib's should be rebuild-ed if you want to use it in OS4. Thank you Laurent!!!